# When rebinding command with [remap ...] which key is bound?

Tags: key-bindings

If command `command` is bound to 2 keys `kb1` and `kb2`, and if I remap like this `(define-key somemap [remap command] #'some-other-command)`, which of `kb1` and `kb2` is now bound to `some-other-command` in `somemap`?

Answer (score 3):

The first command (`command`) is remapped to ***all*** of the keys bound to the second command (`some-other-command`).

See the Elisp manual, node [Remapping Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html).

---

**Update**, to try to answer your question in your comment:

Whether `some-other-command` (which is typically just a symbol here) is already a command bound to some keys, or is even already defined as a command, is irrelevant.

What the `[remap...]` does is create a key binding for `command`, so that *IF* `some-other-command` does become defined and bound to some key(s) *THEN* it will have its key(s) remapped so they invoke `command` instead.

The binding that is created for `command` is special.  It just holds the information that "***any keys bound to `some-other-command` are to be rerouted to  invoke `command` instead.***"

You can think of this binding as being a "**Detour**" sign on the road that would normally lead to `some-other-command`.  When you hit the key Emacs follows the detour sign and ends up at `command` instead of `some-other-command`.

"Remap" means to use `some-other-command` as a pointer (indirection), so that key lookup goes past/through `some-other-command` to finally end up invoking `command`.

Let me know if this is still not clear, and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: Thanks. I read this document several times before asking the question. I don't understand your answer. You say "all of the keys bound to the second command some-other-command", but this command is not bound to any key before the evaluation of define-key. I'm lost. Also, could you please tell me what you exactly mean by remap?